# Task host doesn't exit in time - Windows Phone 8 app error

Tags: windows-phone-8

My Windows Phone 8 app in the Store came up with this error in the crash log...

taskhost.exe!_TaskHost_doesn_t_exit_in_time,_expecting_process_goes_away!

Does anyone know what causes this error?

Thanks

Comment: Same crash started to appear in my Dev Center. I suspect it has something to do with AdMediator, do you use it too?